# how move to another fragment on animation end

Tags: java, android

1- in onCreate method of MainActivity we load SplashFragment using:

```
loadFragment(new SplashFragment(), this);
```

2- then in onViewCreated method of SplashFragment we have an animation. we want move to RegisterFragment after animation end using:

```
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        loadFragment(new RegisterFragment(), getActivity());
    }
```

1-works

2-not works!

why?! how can we solve it?

Note: our loadFragment method placed in adapter class:

```
 public static void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting? Maybe it's a context thing. Does the app crash, or does it give you an unwanted screen?

Comment: no. no error. no crash. app do nothing! just stay in splash fragment!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try Running it on UI Thread since it could be a thread issue.**

```
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   loadFragment(new RegisterFragment(), getActivity());
               }
        });
    }
```